# Running python function during Tensorflow data loading

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I have a function which loads data for training using the string_input_producer function and decode_png function. I would like to run a filter on the image in an on the fly manner, rather than preprocessing all the data. This function (line 60 - bm3d) takes a numpy ndarray as input and produces the filtered array as output.

I cannot figure out how to apply this function to each input image. It has to be applied at that point in the code before resizing happens. How can this be done?

```
def load_examples():
if a.input_dir is None or not os.path.exists(a.input_dir):
    raise Exception("input_dir does not exist")

input_paths = glob.glob(os.path.join(a.input_dir, "*.jpg"))
decode = tf.image.decode_jpeg
if len(input_paths) == 0:
    input_paths = glob.glob(os.path.join(a.input_dir, "*.png"))
    decode = tf.image.decode_png

if len(input_paths) == 0:
    raise Exception("input_dir contains no image files")

def get_name(path):
    name, _ = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(path))
    return name

# if the image names are numbers, sort by the value rather than asciibetically
# having sorted inputs means that the outputs are sorted in test mode
if all(get_name(path).isdigit() for path in input_paths):
    input_paths = sorted(input_paths, key=lambda path: int(get_name(path)))
else:
    input_paths = sorted(input_paths)

with tf.name_scope("load_images"):
    path_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(input_paths, shuffle=a.mode == "train")
    reader = tf.WholeFileReader()
    paths, contents = reader.read(path_queue)
    raw_input = decode(contents)
    raw_input = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(raw_input, dtype=tf.float32)

    assertion = tf.assert_equal(tf.shape(raw_input)[2], 1, message="image does not have 1 channel")
    with tf.control_dependencies([assertion]):
        raw_input = tf.identity(raw_input)

    raw_input.set_shape([None, None, 1])

    # break apart image pair and move to range [-1, 1]
    width = tf.shape(raw_input)[1] # [height, width, channels]
    flag_input = (a.which_direction == "AtoB")
    a_images = preprocess(raw_input[:,:width//2,:])
    b_images = preprocess(raw_input[:,width//2:,:])

if a.which_direction == "AtoB":
    inputs, targets = [a_images, b_images]
elif a.which_direction == "BtoA":
    inputs, targets = [b_images, a_images]
else:
    raise Exception("invalid direction")

# synchronize seed for image operations so that we do the same operations to both
# input and output images
seed = random.randint(0, 2**31 - 1)
def transform(image, inputs=True):
    r = image
    if a.flip:
        r = tf.image.random_flip_left_right(r, seed=seed)

    if a.bm3d and inputs:
        r = tf.py_func(bm3d_filt, [r], tf.float32)

    # area produces a nice downscaling, but does nearest neighbor for upscaling
    # assume we're going to be doing downscaling here
    r = tf.image.resize_images(r, [a.scale_size, a.scale_size], method=tf.image.ResizeMethod.AREA)

    offset = tf.cast(tf.floor(tf.random_uniform([2], 0, a.scale_size - CROP_SIZE + 1, seed=seed)), dtype=tf.int32)
    if a.scale_size > CROP_SIZE:
        r = tf.image.crop_to_bounding_box(r, offset[0], offset[1], CROP_SIZE, CROP_SIZE)
    elif a.scale_size < CROP_SIZE:
        raise Exception("scale size cannot be less than crop size")
    return r

with tf.name_scope("input_images"):
    input_images = transform(inputs, inputs=True)

with tf.name_scope("target_images", inputs=False):
    target_images = transform(targets)

paths_batch, inputs_batch, targets_batch = tf.train.batch([paths, input_images, target_images], batch_size=a.batch_size)
steps_per_epoch = int(math.ceil(len(input_paths) / a.batch_size))

return Examples(
    paths=paths_batch,
    inputs=inputs_batch,
    targets=targets_batch,
    count=len(input_paths),
    steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
)
```

The error from Python is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "pix2pix_mod.py", line 709, in <module>
  main()
File "pix2pix_mod.py", line 508, in main
  examples = load_examples()
File "pix2pix_mod.py", line 192, in load_examples
  input_images = transform(inputs, inputs=True)
File "pix2pix_mod.py", line 182, in transform
  r = tf.image.resize_images(r, [a.scale_size, a.scale_size], 
                    method=tf.image.ResizeMethod.AREA)
File "/home/ne63wog/anaconda3/envs/pix2pix/lib/python3.5/site-
packages/tensorflow/python/ops/image_ops_impl.py", line 741, in 
resize_images
   raise ValueError('\'images\' contains no shape.')
ValueError: 'images' contains no shape.
```

Comment: It's difficult to know what your specific problem is without any error trace.

Comment: I have added the error trace